# MySQL column values capitalized from UPPERCASE

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

This might be a duplicate but not getting my query to work.

I have a column named `region_name` inside table `wine_region`. All my values inside the column `region_name` is at this moment UPPERCASE.

I would like to make it Capitalized using one query within the database.

i got this but its not working, showing errors.

**MySQL(phpMyAdmin)**

```
 UPDATE `wine_region`
 SET `region_name` = CONCAT(UCASE(LEFT(`region_name`, 1)), 
 LCASE(SUBSTRING(`region_name`, 2)));
```

could be a simple typo but at this point im getting a list of errors staring at 
 --> `(LEFT`

Comment: The SQL is fine: http://rextester.com/JGM31616.  How are you calling this in php?  This may error if: you don't have a table named `wine_region`, don't have a column named `region_name` in in that table, you're connecting with an user that doesn't have permissions to the table with that column in it, the SQL string being executed isn't what you think it is.

Comment: Having access to the database im doing the query within the database? and i definitely have the table and also the column. it throws error on this line `(LEFT...`

Comment: Never mind , Thanks, with errors just said execute query and it did it successfully. thanks for the tips and help @xQbert